# Installed latest Ubuntu Server on Unraid VM. Ubuntu says it's out of space despite plenty being allocated

Tags: server, partitioning, gparted

I booted into gparted and increased the partition size to 1TB after increasing it in the Unraid gui. Despite that Ubuntu thinks it only has 100g to work with.

My server errors out after being online for about 5 minutes due to being "out of space". Which also means I can't SSH into it and have been having to use noVNC.

I'm sure there is something incredibly simple I'm missing but it escapes me. Thanks in advance.

See below.

[Unraid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7dwR.png)

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yiD0.jpg)

[Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNTcW.jpg)

Comment: Hello. Please do not show pictures of text. Cut and paste into the body of the question.

Comment: The partition appears to be a physical volume for LVM. Did you extend the logical volume and resize the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

As others had suggested I had to extend the LVM  partition. Here's what I had to do.

```
sudo -i
```

This will switch you to the root user. Then

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
```

Then

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```